# Displaying AJAX responses in the same order they were sent out without using synchronous requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sending out multiple getJSON requests, and after each request I build out a panel and initialize a 3rd party hierarchical grid with the data. The problem I'm having is that panels aren't being created in the order the requests are sent out but in the order they come back. I think I've dug myself into a whole but I really don't want to have to re-engineer this if I don't have to.

```
var _grids = {
        ServiceGrid: {
            id: 0,
            parentUrl: _SERVICE_CONTENT_URL,
            childUrl: _SERVICE_HISTORY_URL,
            parentElementName: "ServiceTypeName",
            childElementName: "ServiceLogEntries",
            childPrimaryKey: "LogID",
            tableName: "Service",
            data: [],
            parentColumns: [...],
            childColumns: [...]
        },
        ServiceItemGrid: {
            id: 1,
            parentUrl: _SERVICE_ITEM_CONTENT_URL,
            childUrl: _SERVICE_ITEM_HISTORY_URL,
            parentElementName: "PackageServiceItemName",
            childElementName: "ServiceItemLogEntries",
            childPrimaryKey: "LogID",
            tableName: "Service Item",
            data: [],
            parentColumns: [...],
            childColumns: [...]
        }
    };

function prepareDataForGrid(_grids, id) {
    var tableIdIncrementor = 0;
    var $panelGroup = $("<div>").addClass("panel-group");

    // Append Accordion
    $panelGroup.attr("id", "accordion");
    $panelGroup.appendTo("#placeholder");


    $.each(_grids, function(index, grid) {
        var parentUrl = grid.parentUrl,
            childUrl = grid.childUrl,
            //Request data
            parentData = getApiDataAjax(parentUrl, id),
            childData = getApiDataAjax(childUrl, id);

        $.when(parentData, childData).done(function (parentDataResult, childDataResult) {
            //Combine child to parent
            combineElements(parentDataResult[0], childDataResult[0], grid);
            // Hydrate grid.data with combined data
            grid.data = parentDataResult[0];

            //loop through grids, build panels for each parent
            $.each(grid.data.result, function(index, value) {

                appendhtml(grid, value, tableIdIncrementor);

                //Create hierarchical grid  
                $("#" + tableIdIncrementor).igHierarchicalGrid({
                    initialDataBindDepth: 1,
                    dataSource: JSON.stringify(value),
                    dataSourceType: "json",
                    responseDataKey: "result",
                    autoGenerateColumns: false,
                    primaryKey: "ID",
                    columns: grid.parentColumns,
                    autoGenerateLayouts: false,
                    defaultChildrenDataProperty: value[grid.childElementName],
                    columnLayouts: [
                        {
                            key: grid.childElementName,
                            autoGenerateColumns: false,
                            primaryKey: value.childPrimaryKey,
                            columns: grid.childColumns
                        }
                    ]
                });

                tableIdIncrementor++;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I could possibly make all the panels first and attach the grids to the panels via id's but it would be so much simpler if I could append panels and grids in the order the requests where sent out.

Thanks.

Comment: Stick them all in one more $.when, since the callback will have the data in the correct order within the arguments.

Comment: I wondered about that but I didn't think I could (I don't know how) because future ajax calls could take place but I don't have any way of knowing before hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution would be to create and append a div to the target div while you're looping, then insert data into each div as the data arrives.

```
$.each(function () {
    var $thisDiv = $("<div>").appendTo("#targetDiv");
    $.when(doThis,doThat).done(function (result1, result2) {
        $thisDiv.append(result1).append(result2);
    });
});
```

Though, I would prefer building the html structure beforehand and inserting all at once, just because I prefer to touch the dom as little as possible.

Comment: The difference is i'm creating and appending the div before any asynchronous actions have happened, resulting in it being appended in the exact order they were sent. I then later update the divs with the result.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now, but I wont know how many panels I'll need until the results come back.

Comment: i don't think that matters.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm asking the right question or looking for the right answer. The grid object that being looped through could have an array of results come back in both the ServiceGrid and ServiceItemGrid. Sometimes the ServiceItemGrid data comes back first and therefore paints on the page first.But I need ServiceGrid data to be displayed first. With your solution the div could still be appended with ServiceItemGrid results and end up on the page first. This is my first attempted at working with data in this manner and I thank you very much for helping.