# jQuery JSON queries - order is random

Tags: jquery, json

Look at this Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPeqBQ

```
var streamers = ["WagamamaTV", "losty123", "BlackDotATV", "Dendi", "VITALIC_DOTA2", "Singsing", "zonixxcs", "Attackerdota", "purgegamers", "Mikerina","ESL_LOL","jcarverpoker", "gnumme"];
```

The code query looks as follows:

```
$.each(streamers, function(key, value) {
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + value, function(channel) {
      if (channel["stream"] == null) {
        // ADD TABLE ROW WITH DATA (for details see codepen
      } else {
        // ADD TABLE ROW WITH DATA (for details see codepen)
      }
    });
});
```

The Order in which the table rows are added is more or less random. Can I influence this order somehow so that it preserves the original order given in the array "streamers"? Just go to the codepen and refresh it a few times, you'll see what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: Related, but maybe not a good enough dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023574/displaying-ajax-responses-in-the-same-order-they-were-sent-out-without-using-syn

Comment: Yes, use `when` `done` like @KevinB suggested. `getJSON` is asynchronous. What's happening in your case is that you create a bunch of ajax requests in a loop, but they don't wait on each other, and they don't finish in the same order they were created. That's why you see this randomness.

Comment: I think if you replaced `$.when(dothis,dothat)` with `$.getJSON()` in my answer it would solve this problem. Initially when i revoked my binding dupe vote I did it because i wasn't sure at the time if it was in fact doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your AJAX calls are all running at the same time!  They may not finish in the same order.  One may be a bit faster or slower, so the order isn't the same.

To fix this, you can use promises.  Basically, wait until *all* requests are done, then display the results in the same order.

P.S. You can use `channel.stream` instead of `channel["stream"]`.

```
// Array shortened for example
var streamers = ["WagamamaTV", "losty123", "BlackDotATV", "Dendi"],
    promises = [];

$.each(streamers, function(key, value){
    // Push the promise into the array
    // We'll take care of the callback and building the table later
    promises.push($.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + value));
});

// Now wait until *all* of the requests are done
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){
    // This function is passed one argument for each AJAX call,
    // they are passed in order.  So, we can loop over `arguments`
    // to get them in order
    $.each(arguments, function(key, val){
        // Each parameter is actually an array, it's what is normally returned
        // from an AJAX call: `[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`
        var channel = val[0],
            value = streamers[key];

        if (channel.stream == null) {
            // ADD TABLE ROW WITH DATA (for details see codepen)
        } else {
            // ADD TABLE ROW WITH DATA (for details see codepen)
        }
    });
});
```

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZpyXZ

Docs for `$.when` (See "Examples"): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Incredible! Thank you for your answer! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is to  pre built the table in the desidered order with each line hidden and as soon as a response arrive do the work.

In this way you will  reduce the success part of your getJSON to only the minimum work required to render the full lines.

```js
$(function () {
  var streamers = ["WagamamaTV",
                   "losty123",
                   "BlackDotATV",
                   "Dendi",
                   "VITALIC_DOTA2",
                   "Singsing",
                   "zonixxcs",
                   "Attackerdota",
                   "purgegamers",
                   "Mikerina",
                   "ESL_LOL",
                   "jcarverpoker",
                   "gnumme"];

  // build before the full table....
  var cachedEle = $(".streamertable");
  $.each(streamers, function(key, value) {
    cachedEle.append("<tr style='display: none;'><td class='td-stream'>" + value + "</td><td class='td-stream' id='onoff" + value + "'>OFFLINE</td><td class='td-stream' id='viewers" + value + "'>-</td><td class='td-stream' id='game" + value + "'>-</td><td class='td-stream'><a href='http://twitch.tv/" + value + "'>KLICK</a></td></tr>");
  });

  // for each getJSON do only table updating
  $.each(streamers, function(key, value) {
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + value, function(channel) {
      if (channel["stream"] == null) {
        $('#onoff' + value).text('OFFLINE').css("color", "red");
      } else {
        $('#viewers' + value).text(channel.stream.viewers);
        $('#game' + value).text(channel.stream.game);
        $('#onoff' + value).text('ONLINE').css("color", "blue");
      }
      $("#onoff" + value).parent('tr').show();
    });
  });
  $(".islive").html("Streams checked!");
});
```

```css
.streamertable {
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 700px;
}

.td-stream {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <span class="islive">Checking Stream Status...</span>
</div>


<table class="streamertable" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="td-stream" style="font-weight: bold">Name</td>
        <td class="td-stream" style="font-weight: bold">Online</td>
        <td class="td-stream" style="font-weight: bold">Viewers</td>
        <td class="td-stream" style="font-weight: bold">Game</td>
        <td class="td-stream" style="font-weight: bold">Link</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Really appreciate, you put so much work in this answer!